# DoctorKafka Metrics Collector (KafkaMetricsCollector) returning no brokers from zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to get [DoctorKafka](https://github.com/pinterest/doctorkafka) running to decide if it was right choice for load balancing brokers in Kafka.

I have been struggling to get the Kafka metrics collector to start on broker. I have Kafka cluster running locally with 3 brokers on localhost (on ports 9092-9094)

This is the command I use to run stored in start.sh file.

```
java -server \
     -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:../config/log4j2.xml \
     -cp lib/*:kafkastats-0.2.4.9.jar \
     com.pinterest.doctorkafka.stats.KafkaStatsMain \
     -broker 127.0.0.1:9092 \
     -jmxport 9999 \
     -topic brokerstats \
     -zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181/cluster1 \
     -uptimeinseconds 3600 \
     -pollingintervalinseconds 60 \
     -ostrichport 2051 \
     -tsdhostport localhost:18126 \
     -kafka_config ~/oss/kafka/config/server1.properties \
     -producer_config ~/oss/kafka/config/producer1.properties \
     -primary_network_ifacename eth0
```

So when I run:

```
 sudo ./start.sh
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    zkUrl:127.0.0.1:2181/cluster1
    secPro:PLAINTEXT
    brokerStr:null
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:460)
            at com.pinterest.doctorkafka.util.OperatorUtil.createKafkaProducerProperties(OperatorUtil.java:239)
            at com.pinterest.doctorkafka.stats.KafkaAvroPublisher.<init>(KafkaAvroPublisher.java:62)
            at com.pinterest.doctorkafka.stats.KafkaStatsMain.main(KafkaStatsMain.java:135)
```

The list of brokers is empty. When I use zookeeper shell directly I retrieve 3 active brokers just fine.

```
bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181
ls /brokers/ids
[1, 2, 3]
```

I raised an [issue](https://github.com/pinterest/doctorkafka/issues/225) as well in the github.
Can someone try DoctorKafka out and see what I might be doing wrong here? Any help / pointers are really appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles over this, there were a lot of issues here, some on the github page, others are not. I had to change some code and catch some exceptions to get it to work. If you are considering DoctorKafka, think again it might not be worth your time. Look into CruiseControl by LinkedIn.

Comment: See the issues here: https://github.com/pinterest/doctorkafka/issues and the fundamental architecture problem described here: https://github.com/pinterest/doctorkafka/issues/228

Comment: If you are still interested in the discussion - see issue here https://github.com/pinterest/doctorkafka/issues/225